# Angular 2 form control undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an angular 2 component that has a form with some controls, and in my html I use the valid property of the "categories" control and it complains:

> Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

on this line of html code: `[ngClass]="{'no-error': addForm.controls.categories.valid ||`

component class:

```
export class AddFormComponent implements OnInit {

  private addForm: FormGroup;
  private mealSelected: boolean;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            categories: [null, Validators.required],
            mealTypes: [[], this.mealTypesValidator()],
            brand: [null, Validators.required],
            name: [null, Validators.required],
            description: [null, Validators.required],
      image: null,
            webUrl: null,
        });
    }...
```

component html:

```
    <small 
        [ngClass]="{'no-error': addForm.controls.categories.valid || 
        (addForm.controls.categories.pristine && !submitted)}" 
        class="text-danger">Please select at least 1 category.
    </small>
```

So it is saying that `addForm.controls.categories` is not defined. How can this be, when I am defining `addForm.controls.categories` in `ngOnInit`? There is probably something obvious that I'm too slow to spot.

EDIT: wait, forgot to add in that the html above is inside this:

`<form class="text-uppercase" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #addForm="ngForm">`

Comment: Can you move the form builder to constructor and try again?

Comment: @echonax didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form tag HTML as below :

```
<form class="text-uppercase" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="addForm">
```

As you have declared `addForm` as `FormGroup` you have to use [FormGroupDirective](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroupDirective-directive.html) for form not 'ngForm'

Answer (score 4):

You need to inport FormControl

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```